# Cannot find the partition where I have installed windows after I have installed arch linux and grub

Tags: linux, arch-linux, windows, grub2, grub

I have three partitions in my system. */dev/sda1*, */dev/sda2* and */dev/sda3*.

1. */dev/sda1* is 50gb for system files for windows
2. */dev/sda2* is for the partition where windows is installed
3. */dev/sda3* is where arch linux and the grub is installed

But when I reboot the system, only the arch linux is showing on the menu. How would I add the windows partition in  the grub menu?

Comment: Do you have os-prober installed?

Comment: no, I don't have os-prober installed

Comment: According to the Arch Linux Wiki: "To have grub-mkconfig search for other installed systems, install os-prober.".  Seems like it's worth a try anyway.